# Listing Buckets (owned and I was given access ) using java s3 sdk

Tags: java, amazon-s3

ListBuckets() in s3 java SDK only lists the buckets I created but I want to List all the buckets in which I have read/write access.

```
 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
            .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(credential.getEndpoint(), null))
            .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
            .build();
    List<Bucket> buckets = s3Client.listBuckets();
```

Comment: Try to show your effort so far, and paste your code

Comment: Added code as you mentioned @howie

Comment: use https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/AccessControlList.html to see if other object you have read access.